# UITabBarController disappers after navigating to another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbaritem

Show `TabBarController` are user `navigation` from another `UIViewController`.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
CategoryViewController *categoryViewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CategoryViewController"];
[self.tabBarController.navigationController pushViewController:categoryViewController animated:YES];
```

After navigating from `UITabBarController` to another `UIViewController` class i.e., `CategoryViewController` the `tabbarcontroller` disappears,  I want to show the `UITabBarController` even its navigate to another `controller`.

Comment: why are do you want to push in tabbar controller ? You can navigate in navigation controller of selected view.

Comment: It looks like you have your `UITabBarController` in the view hierarchy of your `UINavigationController`. If you `push` another view controller onto the stack, *of course* it will push the `UITabBarController` away. You either have your design backwards, or you need to show how you have set up your hierarchy.

Comment: use simply 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:categoryViewController animated:YES];

Comment: @Shubhambairagi this will remove `tabbar` from the bottom!

Comment: @AnuragSharma, if tabbar items are UIViewControllers then you are right
for above code we need to set UINavigationControllers for tab bar items

Comment: yes, we need a different `UINavigationController` for this issue

Comment: @AnuragSharma - this your comment is already in my answer, yet you downvoted and copied.

Comment: I am not talking about the `Navigation Controller` `TabBar`  has

Comment: You need to parent the navigation controller in the tabbar controller instead of vice versa. Or introduce another navigation controller parented on your tabbar controller, and push the new viewcontroller onto that.

Comment: have you read my answer ? or just down voted by seeing just code?????

Comment: Two more people are wrong right?

Comment: of course they are wrong.

Comment: 100% wrong.....

Comment: show me how i m wrong if you can

Comment: post screenshot of stoaryboard...

Comment: @DonMag Thanks I have changed my hierarchy: by adding UITabbarController a UIViewController along with UINavigationController.

Answer (score -1):

You are pushing your Next view controller at the place of your tabbar

```
[self.tabBarController.navigationController pushViewController:categoryViewController animated:YES];
```

The above line will push your next view controller.

To resolve the issue you have to embed your current view controller (Which is being displayed in selected tab) in navigation controller and use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER animated:YES];
```

Comment: you need to understand that the `navigationController` has the `tabBar` so make sure you test your code before posting!

Comment: @AnuragSharma - Read the lines above the code. The current view controller from which he is pushing to next view controller i told him to embed in navigation controller.

Comment: so [self.navigationController ] will refer to navigation controller in which the current view controller is not the navigation controller of tabbar.

Comment: read the description too before down voting or commenting. use your mind little bit.

Comment: have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936114/how-to-push-additional-view-controllers-onto-navigationcontroller-but-keep-the-t) and thank me later!

Comment: Down voters feel free to comment. What is wrong in the answer

Comment: @Dev_Tandel You are correct in your case!  If TabBarController will seuge  with nagivationcontroler and navigationController not be part or rootviewcontroller then it will not show TabbarController.

Comment: Yes , this why i mentioned in my answer : To resolve the issue you have to embed your current view controller (Which is being displayed in selected tab) in navigation controller

Comment: Thank you though, you have post your view on your vote.